# Android, check if back button was pressed before in other Activity

Tags: android, firebase, android-activity, firebase-authentication

I have started to play around with Firebase and made a simple activity to create an account and log in. 
I all works as expected however, I noticed something once a user had logged in and got to the menu screen. If the user pressed on the back button on the android device you would expect that the app would close or go back to where you were before, but because the of the onStart() in LoginActivity it throws back the user to the menu page again. I don't want to change the onStart() method as I like that it logs you if you already have an account. So what I tried was to close the app when back button is pressed in the menu activity like so:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

However, this did not work and I still can't close the app then pressing back button in the menu activty as the LoginActivity still brings me back.

This is the LoginActivity:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // [START declare_auth]
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    // [END declare_auth]

    private static final String TAG = "EmailPassword";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        // [START initialize_auth]
        // Initialize Firebase Auth
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        // [END initialize_auth]

    }

    //here we immediately check if user is already logged in then log in
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser != null)
            updateUI(currentUser);
    }

    private void updateUI(FirebaseUser currentUser) {
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
        Toast.makeText(this, "This is current user: " + currentUser, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        startActivity(mainIntent);
        overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
    }


    public void createAccount(View view) {
        final EditText emailEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email_field);
        final String email = emailEdit.getText().toString();
        final EditText passwordEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_field);
        final String password = passwordEdit.getText().toString();
        Log.d(TAG, "createAccount:" + email);

        // [START create_user_with_email]
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            updateUI(user);
                        } else {

                            try
                            {
                                throw Objects.requireNonNull(task.getException());
                            }
                            // if user enters wrong email.
                            catch (FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException weakPassword)
                            {
                                Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: weak_password");

                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Password to weak", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                            // if user enters wrong password.
                            catch (FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException malformedEmail)
                            {
                                Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: malformed_email");

                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Wrong email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                            catch (FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException existEmail)
                            {
                                Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: exist_email");

                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Email already exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: " + e.getMessage());
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                });
        // [END create_user_with_email]
    }

}
```

Is there a way I can close the app in the menu activity or a way to check in the onStart() method in LoginActivity if we got there through pressing the back button on the phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your intent adding flags `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`
and `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`

```
 private void updateUI(FirebaseUser currentUser) {
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
            mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            Toast.makeText(this, "This is current user: " + currentUser, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            startActivity(mainIntent);
            overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
        }
```

This will close the previous LogicActivity and there is no need to override `onBackPressed()`

Answer (score 0):

LoginActivity will never show anymore with the back button. unless you reopen the application or make an intent there. You can try Adding this.

```
<activity
   android:name=".LoginActivity"
   android:noHistory="true" />
```

Comment: LoginActivity will never show anymore with the back button. unless you reopen the application or make an intent there